# Average over some values, determined by entries from other messages

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

My stream analytics is ingesting a stream of messages of different types. Some are of `type: telemetry`, others are of `type: flags`. I need to calculate the average of  over a moving window of some telemetry values but only consider those values that are preceded by a flag message with a value of true.

Put another way: the flag message turns on/off whether or not the telemetry is considered for calculation of the average.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT
    devId,
    type,
    AVG ("myValue") OVER ( LIMIT DURATION (second, 30) WHEN
        LAG (value) OVER (LIMIT DURATION(minute, 5) WHEN type='flag' and text='myValueFlag') = 1
    ) as 'myValueAvg'
    MAX("ts") as 'ts'
INTO "eventhub-output"
FROM "iothub-input" TIMESTAMP BY "ts"
WHERE type = 'telemetry'
GROUP BY devId, type, SlidingWindow(second, 30)
```

But I get this error message:

> In a query with GROUP BY, Analytic functions can not be used neither in the GROUP BY nor in SELECT, unless they are argument to an aggregate function such as in SUM(LAG(x) OVER(LIMIT DURATION(ss, 5)).

I am not sure how to proceed from here. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/lag-azure-stream-analytics) says

> LAG isn't affected by predicates in the WHERE clause, join conditions in the JOIN clause, or grouping expressions in the GROUP BY clause of the current query because it's evaluated before those clauses.

So I assumed the above query should work.

Comment: Have you tried writing the query in 2 steps using WITH? It should work. I need to double check that doc snippet.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. What exactly would I extract to a WITH clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work, finally. The trick was not to use the `AVG OVER` clause at all. Instead, I am using a simple `AVG` over a subquery in which I filter the relevant datapoints.

```
WITH relevant_data AS (
    SELECT 
        devId, 
        myValue, 
        ts
    FROM "iothub-input" TIMESTAMP by "ts"
    WHERE myValue IS NOT NULL
    AND type = 'telemetry'
    AND LAG (value,1,1) OVER ( LIMIT DURATION(minute, 5) WHEN type='flag' and text='myValueFlag') = 1
)

SELECT 
    devId,
    AVG ( myValue ) as 'myValueAvg',
    MAX("ts") as 'ts'
FROM relevant_data
GROUP BY devId, SlidingWindow(second, 30)
```